# How to center a navbar under a heading?

Tags: html, css, navbar, center

I have a problem laying out and centering the navbar and the table. I want the navbar to be right under the `h2` element and centered. At the moment, the navbar breaks onto the next line. The layout of the table is fine, but it should be centered. I wonder if there is a better technique for making a navbar.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  background-color: #2c2f33;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bet-table {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.bet-table th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px;
}

.bet-table table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}

.nav-g ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-g li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-g a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  float: left;
}

.Choose h3 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #7289da;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-top: 5pc;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #7289da;
}
```

```html
<div id="h-container">
  <h2 class="logo">Betbowl
    <h2>
      <div class="nav-g">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Make-A-Bet</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pending</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Completed</li>

            </ul>
        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Choose">
            <h3>Choose</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="bet-table">
            <table style="width:100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

                <tr>
                  <th>Situation</th>
                  <th>Bet</th>
                  <th>Winner</th>
                  <th>Earnings</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>blank</td>
                  <td>blank</td>
                  <td>blank</td>
                  <td>blank</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>blank</td>
                  <td>blank</td>
                  <td>blank</td>
                  <td>blank</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    
                </tr>
                
              </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to close your `<a>` tags. like this:

```
<a href="https://...">I AM A LINK</a>
```

ul needs to be centered:

```
text-align:center
```

for the table you should remove display property from the container, default value works fine:

```
.bet-table{
    /* display: table-cell; REMOVE THIS LINE */
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

table{
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

find the edited version here: https://codepen.io/theBehrouz/pen/QWmXZbr